# Best way to reference an html element in a js function located in an angular 2 component

Tags: angular, typescript

Newbie in angular 2. 
I have a table where every tr is bind to an object (we'll call it worker). I attached an mouseover event to that tr and I want to display this object instance property (lets say worker.firstname) in another input field on the form.
I manage to make a simple alert of this property when I reach the js function, but I would like to set the input field text with that value.
So, I thought of passing the element as a parameter in the function, like that (using jquery selector which I'm not sure is included):

```
<tr *ngFor = 'let worker of Workers' (mouseover)="showAdditionalData(worker, 
$('#txtWorkerAdditionalData'))" >
```

or maybe using the old getElementByID.
What is the best way of doing it ? 
Attached a code block:
This is the html element I want to populate with the worker firstname:

```
<input type="text" id="txtWorkerAdditionalData" />
```

This is the js function:

```
showAdditionalData(worker: IWorker, element: any) : void{
element.text = worker.FirstName;
alert (worker.FirstName);
}
```

Comment: I would almost guarantee that there's a way to do this in Angular without dropping down to the DOM level. Bind to a property on your component class, or if they're in separate components use `@Input` and `@Output` to communicate up and down.

Comment: General rule of thumb - whenever you're tempted to use jQuery in an Angular/React app, it's usually a sign you're going about things the wrong way. I wouldn't go as far as to say you should *never* do it (not a fan of dogma in web development), but I've not had to install jQuery for several years now and I've never had any issues.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comments - DOM manipulation is rarely the way to go when you're using a library like Angular or React. Half of their appeal is that they handle that stuff for you!

Here's how I'd implement this kind of functionality. Drop the element parameter from `showAdditionalData` and just pass in the worker:

```
<tr *ngFor="let worker of Workers" (mouseover)="showAdditionalData(worker)">
    ...
</tr>
```

Then, grab the first name from the worker and assign it to a field on your component:

```
public currentWorkerName: string = "";

showAdditionalData(worker: IWorker): void {
     this.currentWorkerName = worker.FirstName;
}
```

Now you can bind `currentWorkerName` to your input:

```
<input type="text" (value)="currentWorkerName" />
```

Done! And without a DOM element in sight :)

This answer assumes that both the table and the input are in the same component, but you're not out of luck if that isn't the case - either use `@Input` and `@Output` to pass data/events through the component tree, or pull out `currentWorkerName` into a service and inject it in both components.

Comment: Thanks- that's great. I was looking for a way of binding variable to an input element, but was missing the knowledge.

Comment: Joe Clay - currentWorkerName  is not a part (property) of the current component . (The component currently represent collection of workers), so-I'm getting "Property 'WorkerAdditionalData' does not exists on type 'WorkersComponent'. Am I missing something ?
The  worker is one instance of the workers collection, which the HTML page is its component.

Comment: @GuyE: You need to add it to the component, then. `public currentWorkerName: string = "";` I'll update the answer to make that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reference elements in a template you can use tempate variables and the ViewChild decorator to get the element ref.

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'example',
  template: `
    <tr #templateVariable
      *ngFor = 'let worker of Workers'
      (mouseover)="showAdditionalData(worker, $('#txtWorkerAdditionalData'))">
  `
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('templateVariable') element: ElementRef;

  constructor(
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('element: ', this.element.nativeElement.value);
  }

}
```

You should never access the dom directly as it is against convention and apparently breaks a lot Angular 2 features.

You can read more about [ViewChild and ViewChildren here.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChildren-decorator.html).

Also note that you can use these decorators to get any kind of element even without template variables. Check the above link for examples.

Good luck!